# Error Installing importmap on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having troubling setting up an existing rails application. I am supposed to set up importmap but it is giving me trouble.

If having trouble viewing the uploaded pic, it says "rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'importmap:install'"

[Rails error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7kii.png)

If I run "rails --tasks" importmap:install does show up.

[rails --tasks output snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvNjQ.png)

Comment: Are you on Rails 7? Or did you manually install the importmap-rails gem?

Comment: @MarcusIlgner Rails 7. Sorry, I'm new to this. I ran the command "bundle add importmap-rail" as instructed in the importmap github readme.

Answer (score 0):

As per the attached screenshot of the task list, the actual task name apparently is called `app:importmap:install` instead of `importmap:install`.

I'm not sure why that might be the case, though. It seems to me like you might (accidentally?) be working on a Rails engine instead of an actual app?

Comment: Hello, it seems that there are configuration issues with the project I am working on. I attempted to run "rails restart" and it was also aborted.

Comment: I assume that this is not publicly available anywhere? Debugging what is going on might take some time and is probably out  of scope for a simple SO question 